# Spectroscopy: The trustworthiness of reflected, refracted, and "mixed" light sources

Tags: optics, astrophysics, spectroscopy

Spectroscopy: If spectral lines are used to determine the composition of an object, wouldn’t the reflected light (e.g., from a star) that allows us to see non-luminous objects (e.g., planets, bolides) also include the spectral lines of the light’s source of origin?
For example: If the spectral lines (from the spectrum of) a star shows that its atmosphere is composed of hydrogen, and that light is reflected off of a planet in its orbit that is then captured by a telescope on Earth (that is focusing on the planet), wouldn’t the spectral lines indicate the presence of hydrogen (in the star’s atmosphere) as a “false positive,” in as much as the spectrum from the planet would appear to show that its atmosphere also contains hydrogen?
Also, as lenses with successively larger diameters are used to collect larger swaths of light (in order to perceive more distant celestial objects), wouldn’t “light pollution” from all of the other light sources (i.e., other stars from Earth to the object in question) distort the spectroscopic graph of any one object in particular?  That is, isn’t the source of all the light in a telescope really just an amalgamation of a vast ocean of light sources that has been condensed down into a tiny focus?

Comment: Are you referring to a particular paper? How a particular result was achieved would warrant a more detailed discussion based on what the team really did rather than what you may think they might have done. The control of experimental errors for these kinds of observations is complex and requires a detailed analysis.

Comment: Hi @CuriousOne, thanks for responding--

No, I was only speaking generally.  I am just trying to understand how the process works.

Comment: Unfortunately  there really isn't one "process", especially on observations that require such complex equipment as astronomy and that have so many potential error sources. One has to dig really deep into the methodology chosen by a particular research group to understand how they justify their claims. That's the case with pretty much all of large instrument science. In high energy physics, for instance, you could easily spend a decade on characterizing the error sources of just one detector system and that's what the people who build it do for a living.

Comment: @CuriousOne Oh, I see... How discouraging!  Well, hopefully, as I learn more about the subject I will gain access to more pieces of the overall methodology puzzle.

Comment: Look at it this way... is a skyscraper just a slightly larger house? It may seems so... until you are asked to build one... that doesn't mean that we should be discouraged to build skyscrapers, it just means that it takes slightly longer to learn how to do it right so that they don't collapse on themselves.